# Typescript not throwing error on wrong promise return type

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, null, promise, q

*using `Typescript 2.0.7`*

---

When using `q` Promises even when declaring a defined return type of the function or even the respective `then`, as long as the function might return `null` any type restriction is superseded and wrong resolve types do not throw any error.

```
import Q = require('q');

class Foo {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}

function test () : Q.IPromise<Foo>
{
  return Q.resolve('stuff')
    .then<Foo>(() =>
    {
      if(Math.random() > 0.5)
      {
        return Q.resolve({ id: 3, value: new Foo() }) // This should throw an error
      }
      else
      {
        return Q.resolve(null);
      }
   });
}
```

---

Furthermore when trying to test the same behaviour with ES6 Promises following code did not throw an error either.

```
function test(): Promise<Foo>
{
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('foo');
   })
}
```

---

Could someone explain this behaviour and what to do to get the correct error or is this a bug with TypeScript? (I have seen multiple issues that describe similar situations but none of them could really explain this behaviour)

Answer (score 2):

When you return a non-generic `Promise`, it'll actually be interpreted as `Promise<{}>`, which is is assignable to `Promise<Foo>`. What's why it's now throwing an error on `resolve`, it could be anything.

Your code should be like this to be strongly typed.

```
function test(): Promise<Foo>
{
   return new Promise<Foo>((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('foo'); //compile error here
   })
}
```

Comment: That's what I feared since it leaves space for errors. Any idea on the first one?

Comment: Never used `Q`, but according to it's [typing](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/q/Q.d.ts), it's the resolve method that infer the promised generic type. So it should be `Q.resolve<Foo>`

Comment: True - luckily it is enough to use it only on the `null` resolve like `Q.resolve<Foo>(null)` (otherwise it would resolve as `Promise<any>`) but still rather problematic since TS doesn't assure that the function return type really matches the actual returned value.

Comment: Also on second thought, why is `Promise<{}>` assignable to `Promise<Foo>`? `{}` Isn't assignable to `Foo` after all.

Comment: That's because of the current `Promise` definitions. Issue is here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9953

Comment: Suppose you have `class MyArray<T> { }`. `MyArray<{}>` can be assigned to `MyArray<Foo>`, even a number can do it. There is nothing inside `MyArray` telling that number cannot be it. But if you add a property like `data: T`, it'll enforce the assigned value to be of a type that has a property `data: Foo`. That's the current problem with the `Promise` type. Anything can be a Promise as long as they have the `then` method with the correct signature.